# POST setitem doesn't set value in datawindow

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a response window, `w_response`. Inside that, I have data window `dw_1`, in which I want to validate the data entered. There is a column `c_1`.

When User enters wrong data in c_1 and tabs out, a search window w_2 will open with a OK Button and the user's selection will be set in the c_1 once user clicks OK.This happens properly while we do tabbing out(Used `POST` setitem).

Instead user edits the value(which is incorrect data) in `c_1` and immediately clicks OK in `w_response`.

This triggers search window `w_2`, and although user selected correct value and clicked OK, the wrong value is set in the `c_1`(which is typed by user). Seems like `POST` setitem is not happening properly.

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Are you triggering AcceptText on dw_1 anywhere in your window?  This event is specifically designed for cases where the datawindow control loses focus (by a click on the OK button from your example).  The PB help has more information on this (topic is **AcceptText method**).

Comment: We are using validation with accepttext in ue_ok() of w_1. Below is the code.       IF dw_1.acceptText() = FAILURE THEN RETURN
I even checked with mesagebox after and before setting, and the new value is set as expected.
But in ue_ok(), when i get the value through getitemstring(), i can only see the incorrect value.

Comment: When is ue_ok triggered?

Comment: ue_ok() is triggered when we click OK button in the response window w_1.
I will explain the UI Action performed: I click a check box and the response window w_1 opens, then i enter correct value in c_1 and I tab out. Then I go back to the same column c_1, and enter the incorrect value, and immediately I click OK.
Since I entered incorrect value, search screen w_2 opens, from which I select a valid data, and then I click OK.

Comment: ---At this point ue_ok() of w_1 is triggered,
ue_ok() --->IF dw_1.acceptText() = FAILURE THEN RETURN -->itemchanged()--> OpenWithParm(w_2, lnv_pass)-->after this we are setting the value this.POST setItem(this.getrow(),'c_1',lnv_pass.s_string18)-->i can see correct value till here--> return ancestorreturnvalue(0)(itemchanged event)-->back to ue_ok() where we called accept text which i mentioned earlier and proceeds to check other validations.

Comment: When we use getitemstring of C_1 in ue_ok(), we get the text whatever we entered wrongly, am wondering why i don't get the recently set value(correct) in ue_ok() event. Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you this.POST setitem()?  Why not just this.setitem?  Rememer any POST call will not execute until all other currently running code has completed, or there is a Yield() call.  So it sounds like when you immediately hit OK, the ue_ok calls accepttext which then prompts for the correct data and calls POST setitem, but because the ue_ok code is already running, it must complete before the POSTed call can run.  Try either removing the word POST from the call, or adding a Yield() after accepttext.

Comment: Maybe you need the POST if it's in item changed, I'm not sure.  If you do then try adding the Yield call in ue_ok and see if that helps.